# Why won't my WebApi GlobalExceptionHandler run?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, exception

I followed the instructions in this url: 
https://ruhul.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/how-to-handle-exceptions-globally-in-asp-net-webapi-2/

My Exception Handler looks like this:

```
public class GlobalExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler {
    public override bool ShouldHandle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return base.HandleAsync(context, cancellationToken);
    }


    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        base.Handle(context);
    }
}
```

While my registration looks like this:

`config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler());`

I then tried to hit a route that didn't exist, but the debugger will not break on any of the code in the exception handler.  Instead I go straight to a 404 Error Page with content type text/html and the default ASP.NET error page.

Am I missing something with how this is supposed to work?  I cannot for the life of me figure out why my exception handler won't fire.  My understanding is that the IExceptionHandler should have the opportunity to act on all exceptions, even ones that don't occur in the controller pipeline.

Edit:

I verified that an exception thrown in a controller action IS handled by my global handler.

I have some code running in global.asax.cs's Application_Error that shows that an exception did occur in the Routing Error (404) case.  In the below code, httpError is a valid reference to an HttpException

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     var error = Server.GetLastError();
     var httpError = error as HttpException;
     ....
 }
```

Comment: I don't think 404 throws an exception. Why don't you try explicitly throwing an exception within a know good route and see if you hit the globalhandler.

Comment: It's a good thought but I've verified that its hitting code in Application_Error event with an HttpException in global.asax.cs when I hit the 404.